# NetSuite Renaming Action Button

Tags: netsuite

Is there a way to rename the 'Receive' button on PO record? I thought this could be accomplished by customising the form > Actions > Standard Actions. It seems the action name is used and not the lable. I want action named to be changed to something like Generate Bill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a User Event script to the purchase order and in beforeload event write the below code

```
var rcvBtn = form.getButton('receive'); 
rcvBtn.setLabel('Receive Custom'); //Set as "Generate Bill"
```

1. form.getButton is a method of nlobjForm and it will get the button
   as nlobjButton
2. setLabel is a method for nlobjButton to change the
   label.

[image]
Thanks
Frederick

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet but it's throwing an error: Cannot call method "setLabel" of null. I can't see the issue. I've added the code in User Event Script before load.

Comment: The 'Receive' button doesn't show up in every situation.  You should check if it's null before trying to set the label.  `if (rcvBtn) { rcvBtn.setLabel('Receive Custom'); }`.  This should avoid the "Cannot call method" errors.

Comment: That's resolved the error but the button doesn't update with the custom lable. The Receive button shows when the status is in pending receipt. I've deployed the user event script so not sure what else to try...

Answer (score 0):

You can Change Label from 'Customize form'

> Go to
>
> Customization >> Forms >> Transaction forms
>
> Select 'Standard Purchase Order'
>
> Action(Tab) >> Standard Action(Sub tab)

Just change the **button Label** from **'Receive'** to **'Receive Custom'**

select **preferred** checkbox and save

**Check**
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ba5smd821

Comment: Thanks. Looks like there is a defect since neither approach from above work for me.